# How can I be notified immediately if time machine is not able to make a backup?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, time-machine

My external hard drive sometimes decides not to turn on with my computer. Time machine tries to make a backup, but fails. After ten days of trying to make backups it pops up a warning telling me it hasn't been able to make a backup in ten days.

This is a desktop computer. It isn't like I travel away from home with it where it can't connect to a time-capsule. I would like a warning the first time it is not able to make a backup.

I believe, but have not verified that the time capsule icon in the menu bar changes when it isn't able to make a backup. However that is too subtle for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Growl on your Mac, [TimeMachineGrowler](http://boredzo.org/time-machine-growler/) might be the answer for you.